# Why SIM in Japan for traveller is data only?

Tags: japan, cellphones

When I arrived at Japan, I tried to find a SIM which would allow me to make and receive call. However, SIM was data only.

Why is this?

For examples:

- [I can not make / receive calls (Travel SIM/WiFi)](https://support.sakuramobile.jp/hc/en-us/articles/360020532531-I-can-not-make-receive-calls-Travel-SIM-WiFi-)

> The Travel SIM/WiFi only provides you internet. It does not come with a proper Japanese number, so you will not be able to make / receive calls.